# How do you convert a formatted print statement into a string variable?

Tags: string, esp32

I'm using the following routine to print the current time on the com port. I would like to capture this as a string so I can display it using ePaper.

```cpp
    void printLocalTime()
    {
      time_t rawtime;
      struct tm timeinfo;
      if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo))
      {
        Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
       return;
      }
     Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
    }
```

produces -

> Saturday, May 12 2018 12:18:27

Comment: That's clever. How are you getting Serial.println to respond to that format?

Comment: try CStringBuilder from StreamLib

Comment: @Majenko, it is ESP32 Arduino core package

Comment: Oh, so nothing to do with Arduino then. It's non-standard functionality.

Comment: Personally I'd use sprintf() to place things into a char array - though you'd have to do the textual formatting (day names, etc) yourself.  Or the standard C library functions may work for you (or they may not).

Comment: It probably overloads to call `strftime` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve what you want you probably want to use the "string format time" function `strftime` ([docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/)). You would write the result in a character buffer, which you can also print directly without having to convert it to `String` object.

So, the following code should work:

```cpp
void printLocalTime()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo))
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
   return;
  }
  char timeStringBuff[50]; //50 chars should be enough
  strftime(timeStringBuff, sizeof(timeStringBuff), "%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S", &timeinfo);
  //print like "const char*"
  Serial.println(timeStringBuff);

  //Optional: Construct String object 
  String asString(timeStringBuff);
}
```

The overload for `Serial.print` also does [this exact same thing](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/Print.cpp#L149):

```cpp
size_t Print::print(struct tm * timeinfo, const char * format)
{
    const char * f = format;
    if(!f){
        f = "%c";
    }
    char buf[64];
    size_t written = strftime(buf, 64, f, timeinfo);
    print(buf);
    return written;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, except  '&time_info);' should be &timeinfo);, Just what I was aiming for and missing.

Comment: @SimonMarkham corrected, thanks for spotting.